# What is the point of using the formula $P^{-1}AP =D$ for diagonalization?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I recently learnt what diagonalization is, but I don’t get the point of using the formula $D = P^{-1}AP$ for diagonalization. If we know the eigenvalues after finding them can’t we just put them into a diagonal matrix straight away? What use is there in computing P and $P^{-1}$?

Comment: The equation is intended to illustrate that $A=PDP^{-1}$, since $AP=PD$

Comment: To exponentiate a matrix to the power of $k$, you still require $P$ and $P^{-1}$, since $A^k=PD^kP^{-1}$

Comment: $P$ is a matrix whose columns are eigenvectors ! Don't you think that eigenvectors deserve attention also ?

Comment: Well, Dan, first ask yourself, what is the point of diagonalization?

Comment: The diagonal elements of $D$ (equal indeed to the eigenvalues of $A$) are not a sufficient info to recover your original matrix $A.$ You also need the corresponding eigenvectors, which are contained in $P.$ What would be the point of knowing only the former and not the latter?

Comment: Diagonalization is a particular change of coordinates. A linear map $f:X\to X$, in coordinates, in some basis, is computed as $y=Ax$, where $A$ is the matrix of $f$, and $x,y$ are the coordinates of the input and output in that basis. If you change coordinates $x'=Px$, and $y'=Py$, then $Py'=y=Ax=APx'$. So, $y'=P^{-1}APx'$, is the equation to compute $f$ in the new coordinates. The $P$ gives how to change coordinates.

Comment: "*I recently learnt what diagonalization is*". If so, you did not learn it deeply enough. Notice $A=PDP^{-1}$ but NOT $A=D$.

Comment: @CroCo My point was never that A = D, my point was that there is no point in computing P, as we can get D without computing P. I wasn’t aware of the other applications of having a diagonal matrix, and thought the only point of it was being able to understand a matrix’s properties easily, after other peoples replies I realised there are other applications which require the matrix P

Comment: @DanLupu, you're doing it backwards. By cleverly finding such a matrix $P$, mathematicians decomposed the matrix $A$ into a diagonal one $D$. Due to the fact that you have already been informed of the result, your question is fundamentally futile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I want to calculate powers of $A$ then $A^n=(PDP^{-1})^n=PD^nP^{-1}$ (why?) and since powers of $D$ are easy to calculate this means $A^n$ is easy to calculate as long as we know $P$. So that's why we calculate $P$.

Comment: Furthermore, for any scalar function $f(x)$ which can be specified by a power series, if $A$ has the diagonalization $P D P^{-1}$, then $f(A)$ can be defined as $f(A) = P f(D) P^{-1}$, where $f(D)$ is defined to be a diagonal matrix with $f$ applied to the diagonal entries of $D$.  E.g., $\sin A$ makes sense for diagonalizable $A$ (and, with a little more work, for all square matrices $A$) and it's not just the sine of the entries of $A$.

Comment: @JimFerry I haven’t exactly done functions with matrix inputs so I’m not sure how you calculate those? Is it just applying the function to every element inside the matrix?

Comment: @JimFerry you can only do it to diagonal ones; then you just apply it to the elements. If not diagonal, you first diagonalize

Comment: @DanLupu - "Is it just applying the function to every element inside the matrix". It is very much not this :-). We want $f(x)=x*x$ to correspond to matrix multiplication, and the element wise interpretation doesn't even work there. I wouldn't worry that much about general functions at this point, but making polynomials work well is already helped by having the diagonalizing $P$ matrix.

Comment: "*So that's why we calculate $P$*" but this is not the only reason. This answer shows one of the diagonalization's applications.

Answer (score 2):

Extending @CyclotomicField's answer, let $f(x)$ be a function with a Taylor series (about $0$),
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f^{(n)}(0)\frac{x^n}{n!},$$
valid for $x$ in some radius of convergence. We wish to define $f(A)$, where $A$ is a matrix; a simple way to do this would be to use the Taylor series for $f$. To efficiently compute $A^n$, we diagonalize $A=P^{-1}DP$ so that
$$A^n=P^{-1}D^nP.$$
Thus we can efficiently compute
$$f(A)=P^{-1}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty f^{(n)}(0)\frac{D^n}{n!}\right)P=P^{-1}f(D)P,$$
where $f(D)$ is simply applying $f$ to the diagonal elements (note that we require all of the elements to lie in the in radius of convergence). This has many applications, although a neat one is solve systems of differential equations:
$$\frac{d\mathbf{x}}{dt}=A\mathbf{x}\implies \mathbf{x}(t)=e^{At}\mathbf{x}(0),$$
where $e^{At}$ can be computed using the method above.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a matrix $A$ and a vector $v$, and suppose $D$ is a diagonal version of $A$. If you compute $A v$, you will most likely not get the same result as if you compute $D v$.

Usually you compute the diagonal version of a matrix because it is useful for you in a specific expression. That is why you must in that case substitute $A$ by $P^{-1} D P$ to get an equivalent expression.